# SQL Server Reporting Services - Ability to trigger report generation from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm just starting to explore the Visual Studio Reporting Services and, before I dive deep into the details, I need to know if the following is feasible.

I have a web application that, through a SERVLET, interacts with a SQL Server database (2012).

Now, I need to realize a scenario in which a user (Web Client) clicks on a button, a report is created at the Server's side and a link to the report is returned (so that the user may download it).

The reports could be either in Excel or PDF format.

Since I have an active and perfectly working interface with the database, I would like to have this scenario using the same mechanisms, meaning invoke a stored procedure that would trigger the report generation (to be stored in a pre-defined folder with a pre-defined name).

My questions are:

1. Is this at all possible?
2. If yes, could anyone provide some guidelines on how to tackle this in the right way?

Comment: Yes, You can do it by creating SSRS subscription for the report. Subscription is created in the SQL Server job agent with name something like `‘B4FE7F0D-7FFB-47F5-F87A-D63F2B882A09′`.Once you find the name of the subscription, insert the below query in the stored procedure. Below query executes the subscription.

`USE msdb 
EXEC sp_start_job @job_name = ‘B4FE7F0D-7FFB-47F5-F87A-D63F2B882A09′`

FYI,
Predefined folder and format is defined in the SSRS subscription you create. 
Predefined Name is found in the SQL server job Agent of the report server.

Comment: Thank you @CuriousKid for your input. Could you suggest some good tutorials for SSRS? This is going to be the very first time I bring my hands into this product and it would be very helpful if I could read some **relevant** guides before starting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends what you want to learn. But for starters i would suggest you to go through the below playlist for designing reports in SSRS. 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7A29088C98E92D5F

Comment: Looks interesting @CuriousKid. Thanks for the hint.